# copy dataframe lines and replace on the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, vaex

I have a dataframe in which I have 2 records that are with few values, I wanted to replace those records with others with more values, make a copy.
Does anyone know how to do this on pandas or vaex?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cgiM.png)

wanted to replace the values ​​148 for example with the values ​​140
Someone help?

edit:
my dataframe is this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdH4J.png)

I would like to replace all values of day_of_week = 148 with values of day_of_week = 140
because (day_of_week = 148) has 1000 records and (day_of_week = 140) has 200000 records

I want to copy all lines day_of_year == 140 and replace for all lines that are day_of_year == 148

Comment: please post a small example of your DataFrame

Comment: check my post, i edit @Andre

Comment: I want to copy all lines day_of_year == 140 and replace for all lines that are day_of_year == 148

Comment: Please post a subset of your data in a format we can copy and paste.  Images don't work.  Also, an example of your desired output on that subset would make your question more clear and help you get an answer.

Comment: basically my problem is trying to duplicate rows (where day_of_year == 140) and when doubling change the column value day_of_year to 148 @B.Bogart

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should be straightforward in vaex:

```
df['new_col'] = df.func.where(df.day_of_week==148, 140, df.day_of_week)
```

In vaex the new column will be virtual, i.e. not take any memory. So it does not matter if you overwrite your existing one, or keep a separate one with the mapping (maybe better to keep a separate one, in case you need to debug your process later on).

I think something similar can be done with pandas, using `numpy.where` as it was already commented before me.